# What is your interpretation of the converse of "If two segments from the same exterior point are tangent to a circle, then they are congruent"?

Tags: geometry, solution-verification

Prospective math teacher here. So I am giving a quiz today that I inherited from my Host Teacher. The quiz is over circles, tangents, secants, etc. On the quiz, there is the following question:

> Determine whether the converse of the statement is true or false:
>
> If two segments from the same exterior point are tangent to a circle, then they are congruent.

I am having a pretty equal spread of true and false responses from the students. My question is: how would you interpret the converse of this statement and would you consider it true or false?

With the way the question is worded, I am leaning towards false. For instance, I came up with "If two segments from the same exterior point are congruent, then they are tangent to a circle." One quick way to disprove this interpretation would be to think of the case where drawing two congruent segments originating from a point **A** that connect to the opposite side of the circle at different points **D** and **E**.

Creating this diagram, as long as **AD** and **AE** are congruent this would serve to disprove the converse. Am I wrong in thinking this way? Brain is about tapped out today.

Comment: In your formulation, an obvious question is "what circle?!". Even if you treat a converse as "If two segments from the same exterior point are congruent, then there exists a circle they are tangent to" - even that is false. Consider collinear segments going in opposite directions.

Comment: As a general rule: If you do not know how to solve a problem, never assign it to students. The problem itself is sloppily written since not everything in the sentence is quantified. On substance, under any reasonable interpretation (quantification) the answer is "false."